# design big database with million users

Tags: database, database-design, web

I'm going to design a database for my website, my website will have many users and each user have a "Sub Domain" of my site (like a weblog). each user can write article on his/her blog and other users can write some comments for that post.
this is my question, "What is the best design for Database?", is it better that I create a table for each sub domain (a table for each user that contain that user posts) or create single table for every users?
I search to find answer but I give different answers!! some body told that save all data in a single table because you can write more efficient queries, but some body told save each users data in a separate table because you will reduce rows count and you can search data so fast.
so I don't know witch one i better and why? and please tell the reason please.
for example what does `facebook` do to save users data? does every one has a separate table or all users data (posts) are in a single table?
some body told me that if I use multiple table instead of single table I can use several servers for my database, because each server can easily save some of tables but if save all users data in a single table then using two servers is more difficult.

Comment: One security mistake, and the data for your million users is exposed to the world.  If you don't have the money for a database expert and a website security expert, I hope you do have the money to settle one million lawsuits.

Answer (score 2):

A newsql db like [voltDB](http://voltdb.com/) would probably help by speed if you want to stay with relational databases. If you want a fast db, the indexing is very important, and you can [split your data into multiple tables](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html), if something is repeated, for example you have a list of colors, languages, etc... from where the user can choose.

Designing an application for million users is not just a database issue. Facebook probably does cqrs and event sourcing and uses relational and nosql databases only for read cache purposes, but that's just an opinion... So you need to design a distributed architecture which scales well... Based on your question you don't have much skill by designing applications like that, so I think you should trust somebody with this project, there are many online marketplaces, for example [freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com/) where you can do that.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I need to improve my knowledge and give more information about database design, and don't know an expert person to trust him.

Comment: It can take months or years to become an expert in database design and application design... Are you sure you have the time?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like this http://www.ukwda.org/ and getting some serious help with your project

The question your asking makes it sound like you would probably need help with the infrastructure behind what you would like to do. You're talking about designing something massive.

Good luck with it though!